# Strange issue with SharePoint 2010 'Ribbon' Tabs

Tags: ribbon

I am running SharePoint Server 2010 Beta on Windows Server 2008 R2 as a standalone installation. I have a wierd problem that only seems to occur on the team site template, sites based on other templates seem to be fine.

The tabs on the ribbon bar at the top of the pages are too small and the text gets cut off (See pic below).

I am not sure what might of caused this, possibly a windows update?

I tried uninstalling SP2010 and re-installing but to no avail. Does anyone know if this is a known issue with the beta?

Thanks

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3060/43438994.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3060/43438994.png)

Comment: I get this is Firefox too, it's not just an IE issue...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be your "view" settings.  It was for me.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2062185

Ryan

Answer (score 4):

Verify if JavaScript is fully enabled in IE... I think it's all disabled by default in Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I checked and JavaScript was enabled. It was a very strange issue - I've since rebuilt the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting Internet Explorer in IE7 mode (using the developer tools, F12)?
/WW

Comment: Thanks - ive not tried that ill give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Wictor, just to let you know I tried IE7 mode but this didnt make a difference - I ended up just rebuilding the environment as it was only a boot-to-vhd setup. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. It is very simple Just set your browser Zoom to 100% it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this happens when you change the zoom on your computer. 
Hold control and scroll up or down to make things bigger/smaller. 
You will notice that the ribbon buttons go back and forth between what you show in the picture and the normal state of them.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't modified any CSS files by any chance? Or added some custom CSS, like all TD's width: 20px?

I think it's quite funny that you are only experiencing it on sites based on the Team Site template.

Comment: Hi Jaap, no I havent modified/added any CSS files - its just a default SP2010 installation. I havent had a chance to test IE7 mode yet so ill let you know what happens.